# PhpWord: set a border for each page in the document

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

I'm generating a Microsoft Word document from PHP with PHPWord. I need to set the edge of each page with the traditional box mode like this [example](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001680.htm), but I can not find anything about this in the official PhpWord documentation. Is there a simple way to do this using the PhpWord API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as setting the style of a section and adding content:

Example:

```
 $style = [
        'borderBottomSize' => 1,
        'borderLeftSize' => 1,
        'borderRightSize' => 1,
        'borderTopSize' => 1
    ];

    $section = $word->addSection($style);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It breaks my page.